# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. in .Net Core

Tags: mysql, .net

I am using mysql connection string for connecting with database and sometimes it's working and sometime it is giving error MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'. I have tried all like server Ip , pooling , Cmd level fixes but now it's not working.

I am using asp.net core 2.2 and connection string is as below.

My connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection":"server=localhost;port=3306;database=xxxxx;user=root;Password=xxxxxx;SslMode=None"
```

tried all combination with and without SslMode , Server ip and others..Please help

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. I have done below steps and it's worked out for me.

1. Reset mySql services.
2. Reset iis.
3. Clean build solution.